# Calculate voltage of Led driver required for a given amount of led's

Tags: power-supply

I have built some LED lights for my fish tank using six of these LED lamps:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/261813680886?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

I have tried using this power supply:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/291074673667?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&var=590234643632&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

When I connected the original six white LED lamps they flashed to indicate the 12v 60w driver was being overloaded. I changed it to four LED's two on each string so the circuit was well within the drivers current parameters; however They still flashed, at this point I took a voltage measurement of between 7 and 8 volts when the lights flashed. It did however work with only two LED's connected.

The driver seems to have a fixed voltage at 12v and from what I have read I need a new driver one that compensates for the drop in voltage.

I asked the person from who I bought the LED lamps what the power requirements if the chip were and he said it would be 12v per chip so around 66V? This left me a little confused because the 12v driver worked with two chips.

Is this the correct way to calculate the voltage of the driver required? Please note I found another source for these chips who states the reserve voltage if 5v; however I believe this may be a typo from the Chinese chap and he probably meant reverse voltage. Also; constant current driver so no resistor suggestions please.

Many Thanks,

Ross.

Comment: Gotta agree with Andy.  There's no part number on the E-bay site and no data sheet - not for the power supply, and not for the LEDs, either.  Without accurate data, one guess is as good as another and just as likely to lead to a dead power supply or a dead LED.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere between 9V and 12V the LED will take a current of 900mA. If it does this at 9V and you apply 12V you might be getting a forward current of 3 amps thru the LED. There is no data sheet for the device (that I can find) so it's impossible to be exact.

But, realistically you probably need to put in a current limiting resistor for each LED. What makes you think it has a constant current circuit built into it?

The ebay link is really-really crappy at giving details - for example it states that the output power is 10 watts - this of course is rubbish!

Comment: Hello very many thanks for the answers I appreciate it; so I do in fact have the right voltage but the current is too high?  Here is a link to the other power supply I tried it with which states it is a constant current but is also dimmable. The original post only allowed me 2 links. http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/301589765588?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&var=600478923899&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT I have wired the whole thing up using terminal blocks so getting some sort of inline resistor might be the answer? I used similar but higher voltage chips before and they worked fine with a CC driver?

Comment: No I think you might need current limiting resistors.

Comment: I should add, the power supply of the higher voltage chips that worked had a variable voltage between 22-38v and it was definatley a constant current supply. Would the right constant current supply work though? I am reluctant to add more parts into the unit because I am running out of space too.

Comment: My main message to you is good luck and next time, buy parts with full data sheets.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I listened to some of your music. Your singing voice isn't that bad.

Answer (score 1):

The LEDs need a constant current feed.

The power supply is a constant voltage supply.

You can PROBABLY get an OK result as follows.

Operate ONE LED from the supply with a resistor between supply V+ and LED Vin+.

The power supply is rated at 5A max.
For 6 LEDs the current per LED is 5A/6 ~= 830 mA
Let's work on 800 mA = 0.8A.

LED spec says 9 to 12V.
9V is worst case so start there.
PSU = 12V.
LED = 9V
Resistor = 12-9 = 3V
R = V/I = 3V/.8A = 3.75 Ohms.
A standard value is 3.9 Ohms.
R dissipation = V x I = 3V x 0.8A = 2.4W
R needs to be 3.8 Ohm and say 5W (10 W even better).

Wire PSU+ve - Resistor - LED+ve - LED- - PSU -ve.
ie current flows through resistor and through LED.

Get voltmeter (eg in DMM)

Set to 20V range.
Turn on as above.
Measure voltage across resistor.
Target is 3V.
A bit more [tm] - say up to maybe 3.3V is OK
Lower is better than higher.
Say V across R was 2.9V.
Iactual = V_across_R / R
= 2.9V / 3.9 Ohms ~= 745 mA = OK

If I is too high use a larger R - say 4.7 Ohms
If I is too low use a smaller R BUT be careful - say 3.3Ohms.

Once you have this working OK repeat for all LEDs in parallle.
One R per LED.
R's are cheap, LEDS are not (although yours are a good price)

LEDs will vary in current somewhat. You can fine tine as above if desired.

---

### NBNBNBNB

LEDS MUST have heat sinks.
They will get very hot and die in no time with no heatsinks.
This can be a simple large metal plate of available.
Be sure not to short power supply when connecting LEDs to heat sink.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I have little graphics card heat sinks though I have only been testing at the moment so they are not wired up, but it would be a bad idea to wire them to the same parallel circuit? I provided a link in response to another post to a constant current power supply I used. I am prepared to solder if resistors are a must. However just to complicate things I would like to add four of these LED’s to add a bit of colour: https://www.kiwilighting.com/10w-red-blue-led-emitter.

Comment: Sorry I ran out of characters: Given I will now be buying a new power supply; if I bought the right one would I get away without having to do all that soldering? I made a 10w x  10 parallel circuit with some similar lamps before but had the right power supply and it is still going strong without any resistors.

Comment: @RossCrowther If you parallel LEDs at CV (constant voltage) resistors are needed EXCEPT if the supply hits its limit and starts to sag and approximates a CC (constant current) source. With a CC supply, if supply max oc voltage is > LED specified voltage then N LEDS will share the rated CC at what ever V it takes to force it down their throats. So eg LEDs that are rated at 1A each with a 10A supply - > 10 LEDS average 1A each, 5 LEDS average 2A each, 2 LEDS average 5A each !!! | **BUT** even if a CC supply is used and average current is OK, LEDS will not share exactly due to production ....

Comment: @RossCrowther ... variations. How much it varies deep-ends on LED maker, whether there is any internal series R etc. AND mixing eg red-blue and white almost guarantees that Vf (forward voltage = operating voltage) will vary at rated current amongst LEDS If you parallel red-blue with white and white say 10-12V opn and red-blue say 9-11V then odds are the RB will get over driven and the Wh underdriven deep-ending (again) how many of each. Also the rated Vf may not 
be as said quite because it is a sellers rough guesstimate. 
| If your 10 x 10W worked well without resistors works well for ....

Comment: .... you I'm (genuinely) pleased for you and many people have  agood enough experience - IF all LEDs are run at less than full spec and cooled well then all should be well enough and current imbalance may be ok for your app. || From the RB picture you probably have 3 strings of 4r+3W + 4r. 3Wh x 3.3V ~= 9.9V. Tp balance this 4r would need to be 9.9/4 = 2.5V/red LED which is usually high BUT if LED were chosen for low Vf at 3V then 3 x 3V = 9V/4 = 2.25V red. They MAY tailor red & white Vfs to suit or may not care. Guess which is more likely.| Adding an R per LED is rather quick ...

Comment: ... easy and cheap BUT you may do OK without them. Constant voltage with R's is 2nd best. CC in parallel with no R's is potentially bad. **BEST** is all in series with high voltage capable CC supply at desired current rating. Another story ...

Comment: So what would be the target voltage of the power supply I would need to have then (6 white and 4 coloured) wired in parallel without resistors? Say 10v x 10 or is it not that simple?

Comment: Just bought 10 resistors. Will let you know how it turned out. These should let me use the 12v power supply then?

Comment: @RossCrowther Hopefully. I do not know what resistance the resistors are or the wattage. (It's very hard to try to be the all seeing and semi-all-knowing octopus with a finger in many people's pies  while hanging upside down on the bottom of the world, when one's eyes are the reports or lack of them from people, and one has no ears,  and when what is done may be the progressive logical first trial one suggested (one can (often vainly) hope) or some other semi or fully random alternative. So too here. If the R values are about what I suggested the currents should be about what we hoped for. ...

Comment: ... If not them maybe not. | I suggested starting with 3.9 Ohms with one LED and seeing what the current was. As the LED spec was somewhat loose[tm] What currents will be tbd. What you bought 10 oif I know not. I may find out in due course :-).

Comment: I went with 3.3 ohm resisters, trying to accommodate the higher power consumption of the red and blue chips at 1A each. With only one lamp connected my multi-meter read the voltage across the resistor as 11v and the current between the resistor and the lamp was 2.3A and may be why I still can't power 4 of them. These resistors are too big for my assembly if a 5w 3.9 ohm reister is smaller and I can get away with it I will perhaps buy a few of these instead. Here is a link to resistors I bought; the wrong type I think? ....

Comment: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/231189613154?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&var=530404112119&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT. What should I do??

Comment: @RossCrowther >  "What should I do?" (1) Follow these instructions correctly (2) Realise that what you have written cannot make sense if you have followed instructions. And probably also mean that you are not measuring what you think. Also - presumably LED lights up and is not backwards with current flowing in an internal  protection diode (that SOME LEDS have).Does it light (3) Describe what you are doing in enough words to make it CERTAIN that we can know precisely what you are doing. At present that could be one LED and one resistor (as it should be or several resistors. ...

Comment: @Ross ...  If the V across 3.3 Ohms is 11V then I = V/R = 11/3.3 = 3.333A. As this is <> 2.3A summat aglae. As 3.3:2.3 is more than resistor tolerance allows summat aglae. If the 11V was across the LED then Vr = 12-11 = 1V so I_LED = Ir = Vr/Rr = 1 / 3.3 =~ 300 mA. So summat aglae. If LED is alight and psu is 12V and Rr = 11V then LED cannot light, SO, SUMMAT AGLAE. SO (4) Draw a cct diagram - hand drawn OK but make it at least half neat of EXACTLY what you are doing and draw in voltage measured across all point. ie CCt is (PSU+)-(Resistor)-[LED+ - LED-]-[PSU-ve].   ....

Comment: @RossCrowther ,,, Voltages to show from measurements are Vpsu (+ to -), Vacross R, Vacross LED. Vpsu+ to res-led junction, V r-LED =jn to psu- . (5) [Deja vu] Follow these instructions correctly. | IF you answer and do the above we will get somewhere. If you have not done all above please see [1] above ...

Comment: @RossCrowther That link doesn't work - and looking at it it's not obvious that it's a public reference. If you can paste a link to a valid image into your answer I or others can add it (you need more rep to do it yourself). The junction MUST NOT measure the same as PSU !. Pathe must be PSU+ through resistor through LED back to psu-. Resistor MUST drop voltage if current flows (V = I/R).

Comment: Please find my diagram displayed below: ![Valid XHTML](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=C1CB1071E27784A9&resid=C1CB1071E27784A9%21903&authkey=AHfFd9RyK8IoLGo) I checked the measurements again killing an led in the process; the junction measured the same as PSU and there are two little pieces for taking a measurement on the led it's self I believe. I took the voltage measurement for the resistor at either end of the wires. Hope it sheds some light on things.

Comment: @RossCrowther Does not compute, alas. PSU is shown backwards but, if LED lights, it's not backwards. If R = 3.3 Ohms, as you say, and if V across R = 0.93V, as you say, then I = V/R = 0.93/3.3  = 0.282 A. **IF** R is 0.33 Ohms then I may BE ~= 2.3A, as you say. Or meter may be reading 0.23A. Q!: WHAT RANGE IS AMMETER ON? Q2: WHAT SOCKETS ARE THE METER PROBES IN? || I try not to criticise fair attempts, but that drawing falls rather short. You can surely do better. Post that to list and it would be severely pilloried, and rightly so, alas. Can you access the circuit editor on the answer screen?

Comment: @RossCrowther It's easy to use and allows much tidier diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2mCx0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The bulb does light up. I took the measurements again and voltage fluctuated quite widely as the LED heated up. I don't have my heat sinks wired up at the moment; the plan is to use the same power source if there is any current to spare. I used the 10A setting on my multi-meter, swapping the leads over to the appropriate terminals. I also bypassed the resistor with a wire and measured the voltage across the led as 11.87v, not sure if that helps.

Been looking at this ohms law solver: http://www.ohmslawcalculator.com/led-resistor-calculator and it confirms I need a 3.9 ohm resistor. I think I will go buy a bunch of them, wire the whole thing up, then measure again hopefully that will take me in the right direction.

Comment: \$3.9\Omega \cdot {2.2\text{A}}^2 \approx 18.9\text{W}\$

Comment: P.S. The lower voltage reading from the PSU came because I connected the LED this time.

Comment: @Russell McMahon I should mention that the full circuit of six LEDs splits into two at one of the terminal blocks. With two on one string and four in the other. If this is the cause of the imbalance and why they won't all light up, might experimenting with stringing a few of the superfluous resistors together correct the imbalance on one side?